# What does the triple operator ??? do in this case?

Tags: craft3, templating, php

I know what the null coalescing operator (??) does. I have an example here with 3 operators and I am unsure what it does?

Here is an example that I came across in a script I am trying to debug:

```
{% set eventsButtonLabel = event.eventsButtonLabel ??? 'Book Ticket'|t ??? null %}
```

What is the function of 3 operators?

Answer (score 3):

The `???` operator has been dubbed the "empty coalesce" operator. It's similar to [the "null coalesce" operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) (`??`), but ignores empty strings (`""`) and empty arrays (`[]`) as well.

The empty coalescing operator isn't part of Craft (or Twig) core, which means your site likely has the [Empty Coalesce](https://plugins.craftcms.com/empty-coalesce) or [SEOmatic](https://plugins.craftcms.com/seomatic) plugins installed; both of these plugins add this operator to Twig.

If you want to avoid using that non-standard operator, it can be replaced with the [`|default`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/default.html) Twig filter:

```
{% set eventsButtonLabel = event.eventsButtonLabel|default('Book Ticket'|t) %}
```

(That last `??? null` in your example seems redundant, unless there is a static translation for 'Book Ticket' that is explicitly set to an empty string, and you specifically need the `eventsButtonLabel` variable to be `null` if that is the case).